# cabal install glib makes error

Tags: windows, haskell, installation, glib, cabal

I tried installing gtk2hs in many ways

but have no luck so far

installation always failed with glib issue

So I tried installing glib first

with cabal install glib

but error arise again

the error is this

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
...
...
...
Registering glib-0.12.0...
Installing library in C:\Documents and Settings\dreambook\Application
Data\cabal\glib-0.12.0\ghc-7.0.3
Registering glib-0.12.0...
setup.exe: internal error: unexpected package db stack: [UserPackageDB]
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
glib-0.12.0 failed during the final install step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

my enviornment is Windwos xp sp3 on x86 processor

help

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a known problem according to [google](http://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=unexpected+package+db+stack%3A+%5BUserPackageDB%5D) and [gtk2hs-trac](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/gtk2hs/ticket/1203).

According to the following [haskell-ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/gtk2hs/ticket/1203) try do do the manual install. Either [download glib from hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/glib/0.12.0/glib-0.12.0.tar.gz) or look the tar file up in cabal cache. (I don't know by heart where that is on Windows but it should be somewhere near cabal.exe.

After this unzip the package and look for `Gtk2HsSetup.hs` and change:

```
#if CABAL_VERSION_CHECK(1,10,0)
                                    installedPkgInfo pkg lbi inplace [packageDb]
#else
                                    installedPkgInfo pkg lbi inplace packageDb
#endif
```

to

```
#if CABAL_VERSION_CHECK(1,10,0)
                installedPkgInfo pkg lbi inplace (withPackageDB lbi)
#else
                installedPkgInfo pkg lbi inplace packageDb
#endif
```

After this run `cabal install` in the same directory where you found `gtk2HsSetup.hs` file.

Comment: Instead of downloading the package, you can also run `cabal unpack glib` which downloads and unzips it for you.

Comment: @Alex Ha, it took me a few minutes to realize it extracted to my current directory in cmd.